# wrong date in SimpleDateTime parse

Tags: java, datetime, simpledateformat

This is the string that I have:

```
Sat, Nov 02, 2013 at 5:10 pm
```

I'm trying to parse it into a date time using this formatter:

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, MMM dd, YYYY 'at' K:mm a");
```

However, this is what it returns when I use it to parse the date string:

```
Sat Jan 05 17:10:00 CST 2013
```

I assume I'm getting the formatter wrong, but I can't figure out where.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capital `YYYY` is the format for something called the ["week year"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).  You want the lowercase `yyyy` for the actual year.

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, MMM dd, yyyy 'at' K:mm a");
```

With this change I output the parsed date and get:

```
Sat Nov 02 17:10:00 PDT 2013
```

(I'm in the Pacific time zone.)

Comment: Thanks so much! I knew it was something dumb I was overlooking.